# React three fiber canvas are not updating properly while resizing window and at the same time while open or close react sidebar

Tags: css, typescript, canvas, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am  using react three fiber to plot the point cloud data .Here i am using react three fiber canvas , so while i am resizing the window or website window at same time i am opening or closing the react sidebar i.e top-right alignment to my website then, i am getting a empty space sometimes at right side and somtimes at left side of my website , i thought its re render issue if canva. i tried few ways like changing the website layout or css  , and rearrange components but sill same issue is occuring.Here react sidebar width 270px when its open status and 80px after close. canvas parent div width is 75% and height is 100%.

i tried few ways like changing the website layout or css  , and rearrange components but sill same issue is occuring.If there any solution for this i am very glad

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.